# Running a sql script inside a bat file which calls 3 other sql scripts

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am trying to run the below command inside a bat file

```
echo exit | sqlplus -S TEST_VKR/vkr@Oracle C:\users\vkr\scripts\Master.sql > Output.txt
```

The Master.sql has the following content

```
@@ 01_Script.sql;
@@ 02_Script.sql;
@@ 03_Script.sql;
@@ 04_Script.sql;
```

These scripts when run individually inside the Master.sql returns no error. Having just the first 3 script files in the Master.sql returns no error. When all of the 4 scripts are run together in the Master.sql I suspect an overlap between 03 and 04 which is causing the error.

Is there a way to add a wait step between the sql scripts inside the Master.sql file?

Comment: Try changing the `@@` for just one `@`

Comment: What is the error, what are the scripts doing, and why do you think an "overlap" is the cause of the problem?  Unless one of the scripts is starting a background process using DBMS_JOB or DBMS_SCHEDULER, any command in script 3 should run to completion before the commands in script 4 are called.

Comment: I get an "unable to open file" error. Note:The bat file is in a different folder and the scripts in a different folder

Comment: One answer to your specific question is to have a small PL/SQL block that calls DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP to wait for some amount of time; but I am dubious about your diagnosis.

Comment: So script 4 calls the various scripts that are referenced in the error messages?  Are they in the same folder as the main scripts or a different one?  Are you using @ or @@ to call them?  Sounds like you just have a problem with identifying the proper path to these scripts.

Comment: 01_Script drops all the objects in the DB. 02_Script and 03_Script creates a set of tables. 04_Script creates triggers and indexes on these tables. The bat file is in a different folder. The Master.sql and other sql scripts are in the same folder. I am using @@ as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %a in (0?_Script.sql) do sqlplus -S TEST_VKR/vkr@Oracle %a>>Output.txt
```

or

```
for /l %a in (1,1,4) do sqlplus -S TEST_VKR/vkr@Oracle 0%a_Script.sql>>Output.txt
```

note: Double the `%` in a `batch file` (`%a` to `%%a`) and put echo in front of sqlplus to test the command before applies.